Launching a Notebook job via Databricks VS Code extension not refreshing library dependency
I'm fairly new to this domain so please excuse if my terminology is not entirely accurate.
I have a Scala library for a data pipeline that will run on Databricks via Notebook jobs using Spark. I set up my project so I could use the VS Code extension for databricks.
My databricks.yml file looks something like:
bundle:
  name: my-bundle
artifacts:
  my_lib:
    path: ./
    build: "sbt assembly"
    type: jar
    files:
      - source: ./target/scala-2.12/*.jar
targets:
  dev:
    mode: development
    default: true
    workspace:
      host: https://my-databricks-workspace.cloud-provider.com
resources:
  jobs:
    # [My Job]
    my_job_runner:
      name: "[My Job] Runner Notebook"
      tasks:
        - task_key: my_job_runner_notebook
          existing_cluster_id: my-cluster-id
          notebook_task:
            notebook_path: notebooks/MyJob_Runner.scala
          libraries:
            - jar: ./target/scala-2.12/*.jar

I am able to launch the Notebook job from VS Code's Databricks extension, which is great. However, after the first launch any updates I make to the library are not reflected in the cluster, and so my Notebook fails.
The Extension output in VS Code makes it look like the override of the artifact should be working but this does not happen in reality. Here's the Extension's logs:
2024-10-31 12:52:22.509 [info] deploy: Deploying the bundle for target dev...
2024-10-31 12:52:24.173 [info] deploy: Building my_lib...
2024-10-31 12:52:39.537 [info] deploy: Uploading my-lib-assembly-0.1.0.jar...
2024-10-31 12:52:46.523 [info] deploy: Uploading bundle files to /Workspace/Users/user/.bundle/my-bundle/dev/files...
2024-10-31 12:52:47.157 [info] deploy: Action: PUT: notebooks/MyJob_Runner.scala, src/main/scala/my/job/MyUpdatedFile.scala <--- This is the file I modified in the library
2024-10-31 12:52:47.591 [info] deploy: Uploaded notebooks/MyJob_Runner.scala
2024-10-31 12:52:47.692 [info] deploy: Uploaded src/main/scala/my/job/MyUpdatedFile.scala
2024-10-31 12:52:47.694 [info] deploy: Initial Sync Complete
2024-10-31 12:52:49.741 [info] deploy: Deploying resources...
2024-10-31 12:52:49.747 [info] deploy: Updating deployment state...
2024-10-31 12:52:50.732 [info] deploy: Deployment complete!
2024-10-31 12:52:50.735 [info] deploy: Bundle deployed successfully.
2024-10-31 12:52:50.737 [info] summarize: Refreshing bundle configuration for target dev...
2024-10-31 12:52:53.121 [info] summarize: Bundle configuration refreshed.

Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks in advance for the help!

You can try restarting the cluster before redeploying the job to ensure any cached or older versions of the library are cleared.

thanks! yeah that's what I was hoping to avoid with this workflow basically. The logs seemed to make it look like things are being re-deployed and thus updated but that does not appear to be the case in practice. Restarting the cluster or going serverless would be workarounds.

Are you still facing the issue? @unbekant

@Jahnavi yes. Not sure if an issue per se, or just the wrong expectations from my side. Trying to answer whether my expectations about what the extension should do and its ability to override the libraries in the cluster is right in the first place. If it is, then it's not working.
